# Reading, Updating and Adding to a yml file using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml

I have one yml file.. Its structure is as follows.

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  menu:
    profile: "My Profile"
    my_risk: "My Risk"
  header:
    profile: "My Profile"
    my_risk: "My Risk"
```

And when I am able to get the value of yml file using

```
yml_content = YAML.load_file('config/locales/en.yml')
p yml_content['en']
```

What i want to know is how to get the value `profile` alone which is inside `menu` of `en`
Also i want to know whether we can add a new object like `my_abc: "ABC"` inside `menu` using ruby.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you parse a YAML you get a Hash. So to get into an inner element, all you need to do is:

```
p yml_content['en']['menu']['profile']
# => "My Profile"
```

Also, since it is a hash, all you need to do to *add* to it, is simply assign a new key-value to it:

```
yml_content['en']['menu']['my_abc'] = "ABC"
```